# What is the alternative of deprecated .ix for mixed position-label based selection?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select specific rows and columns but it won't let me use `.iloc` or `.loc` because my column names are not integers.

```
            Madrid  Boston  Tokyo  Shanghai  Kolkota
2014-01-01     -16      22     49       -24       40
2014-01-02     -49      -7     45         2       -6
2014-01-03     -24      41    -22       -11        0
2014-01-04     -28     -14     -2        20       28
2014-01-05     -49      15    -40        -2        3
```

With `.ix` I was able to do this:

```
df.ix[1:5, 'Madrid':'Tokyo']
            Madrid  Boston  Tokyo
2014-01-02     -49      -7     45
2014-01-03     -24      41    -22
2014-01-04     -28     -14     -2
2014-01-05     -49      15    -40
```

Now that `.ix` is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick-and-easy way would be:

```
df.loc[df.index[1:5], "Madrid":"Tokyo"]
```

So, for example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-50,50,(5,5)), index=pd.date_range("2014-01-01", "2014-01-05"), columns=['Madrid', 'Boston', 'Tokyo', 'Shanghai', 'Kolkota'])
>>> df
            Madrid  Boston  Tokyo  Shanghai  Kolkota
2014-01-01     -16      22     49       -24       40
2014-01-02     -49      -7     45         2       -6
2014-01-03     -24      41    -22       -11        0
2014-01-04     -28     -14     -2        20       28
2014-01-05     -49      15    -40        -2        3
>>> df.loc[df.index[1:5], "Madrid":"Tokyo"]
            Madrid  Boston  Tokyo
2014-01-02     -49      -7     45
2014-01-03     -24      41    -22
2014-01-04     -28     -14     -2
2014-01-05     -49      15    -40
```

You can use the same approach to select particular rows, so if you wanted row 0, 2, and 4 (first, third, and fifth) :

```
>>> df.loc[df.index[[0, 2, 4]], "Madrid":"Tokyo"]
            Madrid  Boston  Tokyo
2014-01-01     -16      22     49
2014-01-03     -24      41    -22
2014-01-05     -49      15    -40
```

#### Note

This isn't a Python 2 vs Python 3 thing, rather this has to do with the `pandas` version, with `.ix`-based indexing being [deprecated in `pandas` version 0.20.2](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix)

Comment: Thanks that works like a charm. I have another question, would it be possible to use this but selecting specific rows? Lets say for example if I wanted row 1, 3, and 5 and the same column selection

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying it out just now. Now I am curious to why there would be another square bracket needed within the index brackets?

Comment: @Gary because it is a `list`, so indexers accept `list`/`array` of values to extract specific values in *that order*, so note what happens when you do `df.loc[df.index[[2, 0, 4]], "Madrid":"Tokyo"]` or for that matter, `df.loc[df.index[[0, 2, 4]], ["Tokyo", "Madrid"]]`, but basically, if you didn't have the brackets it would imply multi-dimensional indexing.